# How can I resolve this error message "Compile Error: User-defined type not defined" in Microsoft VBA

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, stored-procedures, adodb

I am new at Microsoft-VBA, and i trying to make Excel run a Stored Procedure in MSSQL Server and add the records to a table created for that purpose. But every time i try to run this to test my code, i get this error message. I have reviewed and implemented some solutions suggested on this forum, but i have not been able to make it work. For example, i have gone to activate the 'Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects Recordset 2.8 Library in Tools > References, but i still get the same error. Will be glad if anybody can review my code and tell me what i am doing wrong.

[This image contains the code and error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bA72.png)

---

```
Sub My_Test_Report()

    Dim objConn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim objCmd As New ADODB.Command
    Dim objParm1 As New ADODB.Parameter
    Dim objRs As New ADODB.Recordset

    objCmd.CommandText = "[Report Queries].[dbo].[My_Test_Report]"
    objCmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    Set objConn = GetNewConnection
    objCmd.ActiveConnection = objConn
    objCmd.Parameters.Refresh
    objCmd(1) = True
    Set objRs = objCmd.Execute

End Sub
```

Comment: Put the code as text not a photo so we can copy paste and test.

Comment: Which line is producing the error?  I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but I know that's not how 'parameter' is spelled...

Comment: Which line errors out?

Comment: @ashleedawg, the line producing the error is the "Dim objConn As New ADODB.Connection"

Comment: @JohnyL  the line producing the error is the "Dim objConn As New ADODB.Connection"

Comment: Then you are missing that library.  You need to add the correct reference.

Comment: Try `2.7`, `2.6`, `2.5` versions of library

Comment: @ScottCraner, This is the code:Sub My_Test_Report()


Dim objConn As New ADODB.Connection    
Dim objCmd As New ADODB.Command    
Dim objParm1 As New ADODB.Paremeter  
Dim objRs As New ADODB.Recordset   

objCmd.CommandText = "[Report Queries].[dbo].[My_Test_Report]" 
objCmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc  

Set objConn = GetNewConnection 
objCmd.ActiveConnection = objConn  

objCmd.Parameters.Refresh


objCmd(1) = True


Set objRs = objCmd.Execute




End Sub

Comment: [edit] the original post.  Do not put code in the comments, it cannot be formatted properly

Comment: @ashleedawg. I made the correction as identified, but it is still giving me the same error message and pointing at the the same code line. Is my connection wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with ashleedawg3, you have 'Paremeter' vs 'Parameter'. When I try to compile, i get the same error with a highlight on that specific line:

[image]

The clue here is the compiler sees a type it DOESNT know about, so you get the "User Defined Type, not defined"

Try adjusting the spelling and see if that fixes it....

Comment: @RJKelly  I made the correction as identified, but it is still giving me the same error message and pointing at the the same code line. Is my connection wrong

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing a second library.  Go **Tools** → **References** and add both:

> ☑ Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library
>
> ☑ Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects Recordset 6.0 Library

(Uncheck any lower versions of the same libraries.)

Note that when given the choice of different versions of the same library, it's generally best to go for the highest available version number.

Comment: i was able to get it to connect. Thank you